# Execution failed for task ':react-native-audio:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: react-native

I tried all the solutions available,they didn't solve my problem. 
Also when i run one of the solution- "gradlew clean", gradlew is not recognized as external or internal command.

Here's screenshot of the both errors :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkc9N.png

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error but for other Package, I cleaned `gradlew` and then run this command `npx jetifier`. this solved my problem. it's worse to try.
you can install `jetifier` from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/jetifier.
hopefully useful.